# How to add value from object in dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have dictionary which is having objects as value, I want to retrieve value from object.

code :

```
 public class Student {

    public let name: String
    public let age: Double

     public init(name: String, age: Double) {
         self.name = name
         self.age = age
     }
}
```

and dictionary as `["1": Student, "2" : Student ]`

How can i add all the ages of student? for 13 + 12.

Comment: The question – as well as the deleted previous one –  is neither related to iOS nor to SwiftUI.

Comment: Do a for loop if you lack in algorithm skills (it might be basic, but it's an important learning step), or you can use a `reduce(into:_:)` or another high level method...

Comment: yeah i am trying for high level function but quite confuse in that

Comment: `let sum = dictionary.values.map(\.age).reduce(0.0, +)`

Comment: @vadian Wouldn't `dict.reduce(into: 0, { $0 += $1.value.age })` avoid two iterations?

Comment: Yes, `reduce(into` is still better.

Comment: @vadian you should post your `reduce(into:)` comment as an answer. I was going to post that, but you beat me to it with your comment.

Comment: @DuncanC Larme deserves the credits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are potential solutions:

```
let dict = ["1": Student(name: "A", age: 13), "2" : Student(name: "B", age: 12)]
```

Side note, there is nothing wrong in doing a manual for loop. It's basic algorithm skills, and it's need to understand higher level methods.

Basic `for` loop:

```
var sumOfAges: Double = 0
for (_, value) in dict {
    sumOfAges += value.age
}
print(sumOfAges)
```

Basic `forEach` loop

```
var sumOfAges2: Double = 0
dict.forEach {
    sumOfAges2 += $0.value.age
}
```

With `reduce(into:_:)`:

```
let sumOfAges3: Double = dict.reduce(into: 0) { partialResult, aKeyValue in
    partialResult += aKeyValue.value.age
}
```

With `reduce(into:_:)`, and using Shorthand Argument Names (which make sense only if you understand the previous step):

```
let sumOfAges4 = dict.reduce(into: 0, { $0 += $1.value.age })
```

Side note, since the output is just a number, `reduce(_:_:)` is enough:

```
let sumOfAges5 = dict.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value.age })
```

Additional possible step, is to transform your dictionary into a simpler data, like an array of Double.

```
let allAges = dict.mapValues { $0.age }
// or let allAges = dict.mapValues { \.age }
// or let allAges = dict.values.map { $0.age }
// or let allAges = dict.values.map { \.age }
// ...
```

You have an array of Double, then, use either a for loop, `forEach`, `reduce(into:_)` again on this "simplified array"
The downside, is that you iterate twice, one for the mapping, one for your calculation.

Edit: Added commented alternative solutions by [@Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus)

Comment: `mapValues(\.age)`

Comment: btw reduce would suffice `reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value.age }`

Comment: Good point. I always tend to priotirize `reduce(into:_:)` over `reduce(_:_:)`, since I usually use more complexe data.